# terraform plan fails when run from Jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I don't know what possessed me to do this.  I am just a tinker so I started following this tutorial. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ I got that to work.  Then I wanted to create a pipeline that would download a terraform docker container and use that to create a docker container.  Here's my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'hashicorp/terraform:light'
            args '-i --entrypoint='
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World from Github.'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls -al'
                sh 'terraform --version'
                sh 'terraform init'
                sh 'terraform plan'
                sh 'ls -al'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "~> 2.13.0"
    }
  }
}

// This didn't work either:
// provider "docker" {}

provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/"   
}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.latest
  name  = "tutorial"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}
```

Here is the error message from my Jenkins console output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform plan
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError pinging Docker server:
 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/. 
Is the docker daemon running?[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0m  with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
[31m│[0m [0m  on main.tf line 10, in provider "docker":
[31m│[0m [0m  10: provider "docker" [4m{[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m╵[0m[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
```

Jenkins is running in a docker container on my Mac laptop:

```
red@Reds-MacBook-Pro ~ % docker ps | grep jenk
8401359dae3e   myjenkins-blueocean:2.346.2-1    "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   19 hours ago    Up 19 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   jenkins-blueocean
507eb2212eb6   docker:dind                      "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   19 hours ago    Up 19 hours   2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2376->2376/tcp                   jenkins-docker
```

Comment: Have you tried `host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"`?

Comment: You are running the terraform inside an container, inside the container the docker daemon from your host is not available unless you specifically expose it.

Comment: Yes this is a DinD situation, so you need to allow that somehow. There are tons of guides for that with explanations about the functionality and security implications for each solution. Also note this is technically a DinDinD situation really, and while you encountered this in a "tinkering" situation, this would almost never occur in a real world environment.